# Embedding Liquibase in a jar with Spring Application

Tags: java, spring, liquibase

I'm getting quite a specific error while trying to embed pure Spring (not Spring Boot) application with liquibase in an uberjar. As soon as SpringLiquibase bean is initialized, it starts looking for something i don't understand:

```
WARNING 7/16/15 3:22 PM: liquibase: No Liquibase-Packages entry found in MANIFEST.MF. Using fallback of entire 'liquibase' package
WARNING 7/16/15 3:28 PM: liquibase: Error initializing SpringLiquibase
java.io.FileNotFoundException: ServletContext resource [/liquibase] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
at org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextResource.getURL(ServletContextResource.java:156)
at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase$SpringResourceOpener.init(SpringLiquibase.java:117)
at liquibase.resource.AbstractResourceAccessor.<init>(AbstractResourceAccessor.java:22)
at liquibase.resource.ClassLoaderResourceAccessor.<init>(ClassLoaderResourceAccessor.java:19)
at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase$SpringResourceOpener.<init>(SpringLiquibase.java:74)
at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.createResourceOpener(SpringLiquibase.java:489)
at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.createLiquibase(SpringLiquibase.java:439)
at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(SpringLiquibase.java:389)
WARNING 7/16/15 3:28 PM: liquibase: Error initializing SpringLiquibase
java.io.FileNotFoundException: ServletContext resource [/liquibase] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
(stacktrace again)
```

I'm aware of Liquibase-Package entry in MANIFEST.MF and filling it using shade plugin (though i don't understand what use does it have) and putting it using shade plugin,  but it doesn't give any effect. What is liquibase looking for and how can i overcome those errors?

Comment: Debugging further i've found that all found resources can't be opened because i haven't set base resource for embedded jetty, so it can't even read the MANIFEST.MF and, as far as i've understood, tries to get directory named `liquibase` to scan it for packages. This fails as well, and the current problem is that jetty doesn't have native handlers for classpath resources within  ServletContextHandler, and it looks like i'll have to create my own org.eclipse.jetty.util.resource.Resource implementation. I'll post it here if i'll come to it.

Comment: I am also getting this error using Undertow + Spring Boot 1.2.5 One Jar + Liquibase.

Comment: AFAIK, manifest entry isn't necessary for running liquibase. Could you post your SpringLiquibase config?

Comment: @Lia i'm afraid i can't, it was over a year ago. The problem was not in missing manifest but in impossibility of reading corresponding files when using jetty; we've switched to tomcat, and the problem had washed away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2654), this issue would be fixed if you create a src/main/webapp folder:

> Incidentally, the root cause is that no src/main/webapp folder exists. As a work around you could create one or set a value in @WebAppConfiguration that points to classpath: folder that actually exists.